# Find max value in table column

Tags: grails

I am creating a version control domain class in Grails:

```
class VersionControl {

    Date dateCreated
    Long versionNumber

    Long getLatestVersionNumber() {
        //return largest versionNumber
    }

}
```

I would like to add a query to get the largest version number stored:

```
Long getLatestVersionNumber()
```

In SQL this query would look more or less as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(versionNumber) FROM VersionControl
```

The function MUST return the value as a long.

What is the correct way to do this in Grails?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [GORM criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria), querying with projections:

```
VersionControl.createCriteria().get {
    projections {
        max "versionNumber"
    }
} as Long
```

Comment: it seems to be from controller. could you provide an example of your view?

Answer (score 6):

```
VersionControl.executeQuery("select max(versionNumber) from VersionControl")
```

This is easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

VersionControl.find("from VersionControl vc max(vc.versionNumber)")

Comment: Grails 2.1.0 does not seem to like the inclusion of MAX within the find query: unexpected token: max near line 1, column 39 [from VersionControl vc max(vc.versionNumber)]

Answer (score 0):

To calculate max in a query, I think the best is the criteria option:

```
def maxVersion = VersionControl.withCriteria {
    projections{
        max 'versionNumber'
    }

}
```

if you want to add a groupby modifier, just add a new line in projections closure like so:

```
VersionControl.withCriteria {
    projections{
        avg 'score'
        groupProperty 'channelId'
    }

}
```